# Can some one tell me whats wrong with this query

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbctemplate

```
UPDATE trans_actual SET comment_id = ? 
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) 
            FROM trans_actual 
            WHERE plan_id = ?)
```

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL
>   grammar SQLException: ORA-02049:
>   timeout: distributed transaction
>   waiting for lock

Its working fine in SQLDeveleloper.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not with the query itself but the context in which it is being run - the "waiting for lock" is likely very important here.

Comment: works fine SQLDevloper but ... bombs in PHP?  i prefer using the sprintf() function to pass variables into a SQL string.  it's possible to send a INT from PHP as a string for use in MYSQL.  if the INT is seen as a string and not a INT then the query will fail.  `$sqlString = sprintf("SELECT * FROM example WHERE id=%d", $varInt);`

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/select-max-id-from-table-where-id-id-2608.html  this might help

Comment: @b_dubb.. in Java Spring

Comment: @b_dubb: You are giving very, very dangerous advice.  Using `sprintf` to pass data into SQL will open you up to SQL injection attacks for parameters that are expected to be strings.

Comment: i'll concede your point.  i assume that the $_POST is being scanned for SQL injection and XSS attacks.  that's a lot to assume.  thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query looks fine. It looks like a transaction lock problem. In this kind of problem, only you can determine where the lock is because you cannot post your whole code here.

Also, you might have other apps accessing the same database. You have to check for transaction isolation levels, concurrency, the whole nine yards.

Have you searched for [ORA-02049](http://www.google.com/search?q=ORA-02049)? It should give you some hints.

Comment: I think query itself locking it I dont know why.....because Its local server and noone else has access to it.

Comment: The obvious question is... if you ran the whole statement in SQL Developer, including the update, did you roll it back before trying to run it again in PHP?

Comment: is it possible that "trans_actual" is a synonym pointing to another instance via a dblink?  Try: select * from all_synonyms where db_link is not null;

Comment: One possibility is that spring is using two different database connections. Perhaps spring has previously performed a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE on the row, using a different database connection, and that lock will not be released until a COMMIT or ROLLBACK is performed on the connection holding the lock.

Comment: @Alex buddy I am able to run that in mysql Developer again and again in no time.

Comment: @Amit, but you are in the same transaction in mysql Developer aren't you? It was a good hunch. Try commit or rollback the transaction, (close mysql Developer, if you will) and then try to run your code, just get that out of our chests :)